# Can I use css-classes as a mixin in a less-file?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, less, mixins, less-mixins

In my `style.less` I'd like to define, that all elements with the class `.element` nested within an element of the class `.group` have the same properties of the bootstrap-class `.col-sm-6`.

Unfortunately I can't directly add the class `.col-sm-6` to the elements.

In that project, bootstrap is available in the folder `tapestry5/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-darkly.css` releative to my `style.less`. (How) Can I also use CSS-classes as mixins within my `style.css`? I tried:

```
@import (reference) "tapestry5/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-darkly.css";

.group .element {
  .col-sm-6;
}
```

Unformtunately I get a Less4J Exception:

```
Could not find mixin named ".col-sm-6". - line 4 - position 3
```

Is it impossible to use CSS as mixins, or is something wrong with my syntax?

Comment: `.col-sm-6` (as well as similar column classes) is defined inside corresponding media query block and because of that it is not available as a mixin out of that block scope. Normally in these cases you'd need to use [`make-*-column` mixins](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-less) provided with Bootstrap sources. Though in you particular case using `extend` instead of mixin should do the trick (i.e. `&:extend(.col-sm-6);`, since `extend` attaches current selector to the extended one it is allowed to point to selectors defined in a media query blocks from within global scope).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change the `css` file you have available to `less` file ending and import it (as all CSS is valid LESS). The less compiler will be able to find and use `.col-sm-6` as a mixin.

```
@import (reference) "tapestry5/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-darkly.less";

.group .element {
  .col-sm-6;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're going to be using the Bootstrap LESS, you may as well make use of their mixins instead of their CSS. As seven-phases-max suggested in his comment, you can use [`make-*-column`](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-less) instead of using the CSS classes.

You'd do this instead:

```
.group .element {
  .make-sm-column(6);
}
```